# how to set variable for"set variable" activity in data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

firstly I create a web activity to get keyvault,and then create a "set variable" activity. when I try to create variable in the "set variable" activity, it shows "no results found".  BTW  I cannot attach screenshot due to less reputation . I refer to [this do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities)c to do execution

attached the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Can you attach screenshot now ? +10 from me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
You should declare a variable first by click blank, then you can select a variable at step3:
[image]

---

After you added ADF managed identity permissions to Get and List secrets.

1. Add a secret to the key valut. Here my secret name is **mysecret**.
   [image]
2. So your URL should looks like https://**your-keyvault-name**.vault.azure.net/secrets/**mysecret**?api-version=7.0
   [image]
3. Add dynamic content `@activity('Web1').output.value` to your Set variable1 activity.
   [image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. :)